# there is no problem with the code but it doesn't work?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I was making an example in Kotlin, although I followed the steps, the program does not work correctly, what is the reason? I shared it with error codes;

In other words, nothing is reflected in the "RecyclerView" object in the activity main, I thought that the values returned null, maybe that's why I added it to all of them, but nothing changed, so I need help. Thank you to everyone who has already answered.

**ActivityMain XML;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="572dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.483" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ActivityMain.KT;**

```
package com.example.lk

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.lk.databinding.ActivityMainBinding



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        val kahramanlar = ArrayList<String>()
        kahramanlar.add("aquaman")
        kahramanlar.add("batman")
        kahramanlar.add("spiderman")

        val kahramanG = ArrayList<Int>()
        val aquamanBitmap = R.drawable.aquaman
        val batmanBitmap = R.drawable.batman
        val spidermanBitmap = R.drawable.spiderman
        kahramanG.add(aquamanBitmap)
        kahramanG.add(batmanBitmap)
        kahramanG.add(spidermanBitmap)



       binding.RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val degerler = reycadapter(kahramanlar)
    if(degerler != null){binding.RecyclerView.adapter = degerler}else { Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Hata2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}

    }
}
```

**recycler_row.xml;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="kahramanAdi"
            type="String" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@{kahramanAdi}"
            android:textColor="#3F51B5"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**reycadapter.kt**

```
package com.example.lk

import android.text.Layout
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder
import com.example.lk.databinding.RecyclerRowBinding


class reycadapter (val kahramanlar : ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<reycadapter.kahramanVH>() {

    class kahramanVH(val binding: RecyclerRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): kahramanVH {
        
     
        val binding = RecyclerRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return kahramanVH(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return kahramanlar.size 
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: kahramanVH, position: Int) {
        val binding = holder.binding
        if(binding !=null){
            binding.textView3.text = kahramanlar[position]
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context,"Hata",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
    }
}
```

**ERRORS;**

```
-- PROCESS ENDED (11401) for package com.example.lk ----------------------------
2023-03-18 04:32:21.437   494-637   installd                installd                             E  Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl301146714.tmp: No such file or directory
2023-03-18 04:32:21.437   494-637   installd                installd                             E  Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl301146714.tmp: No such file or directory
2023-03-18 04:32:21.840 12002-12002 ndroid.keychain         pid-12002                            E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-03-18 04:32:22.292 12031-12031 .apps.wellbeing         pid-12031                            E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (12050) for package com.example.lk ----------------------------
2023-03-18 04:32:22.874  3125-3277  HwDetectorWithState     com...oglequicksearchbox:interactor  E  a: 3
2023-03-18 04:32:23.357   575-627   VerityUtils             system_server                        E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~E8DH5hCdNckox0qr0TSfPg==/com.example.lk-9nVfQlWPduOP1RLWVTn3UQ==/base.apk
2023-03-18 04:32:23.467   575-627   VerityUtils             system_server                        E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~E8DH5hCdNckox0qr0TSfPg==/com.example.lk-9nVfQlWPduOP1RLWVTn3UQ==/base.apk
2023-03-18 04:32:23.969   575-1572  AppOps                  system_server                        E  Bad call made by uid 10104. Package "com.google.android.gms" does not belong to uid 10104.
2023-03-18 04:32:23.985   575-1572  AppOps                  system_server                        E  Bad call made by uid 10104. Package "com.google.android.gms" does not belong to uid 10104.
2023-03-18 04:32:23.993   575-1572  AppOps                  system_server                        E  Bad call made by uid 10104. Package "com.google.android.gms" does not belong to uid 10104.
2023-03-18 04:33:12.408 12175-12175 oid.apps.photos         pid-12175                            E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-03-18 04:33:29.837  7131-12232 constellation           com.google.android.gms               E  [rpc_manager] GetConsent failed with status: egre{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The caller does not have permission, cause=null}
                                                                                                    Exception: 
                                                                                                    egrf: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
                                                                                                        at aaqj.u(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):3)
                                                                                                        at aaqj.e(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):17)
                                                                                                        at aaqj.g(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):0)
                                                                                                        at abhm.a(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):6)
                                                                                                        at abhi.b(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.constellation.EventManager.f(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):340)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.constellation.EventManager.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):32)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):2)
                                                                                                        at yej.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):4)
                                                                                                        at gxa.run(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):3)
                                                                                                        at gwz.run(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):11)
                                                                                                        at czpz.run(:com.google.android.gms@230914047@23.09.14 (190800-515650844):2)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-03-18 04:33:35.322   410-410   android.ha...rvice-mock and....power.stats@1.0-service.mock  E  Failed to getEnergyData
2023-03-18 04:35:35.307   410-410   android.ha...rvice-mock and....power.stats@1.0-service.mock  E  Failed to getEnergyData
2023-03-18 04:35:59.564  7357-7357  A                       com...d.googlequicksearchbox:search  E  onError
                                                                                                    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.m: errorCode: 65561, engine: 2
```

THANKYOU

**GRADLE;**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.lk'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lk"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**EMULATOR:**

emulator photo[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcSHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

First off, please try putting together a better title that summarizes your issue. Not only is "there is no problem with the code but it doesn't work?" not useful, it's wrong, since if the code doesn't work, there is obviously a problem :)

Anyway, my first guess would be the fact that your item layout TextView height is 0 without a bottom constraint:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" <-- THIS SHOULD BE wrap_content
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@{kahramanAdi}"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        
        // OR You should have a bottom constraint
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

I suggest learning to use the tools at your disposable for debugging visual issues like the [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) and the [Show Layout Bounds developer option](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#drawing).

Comment: Thank you for the title suggestion. There was no change when I did what was suggested, thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you use the tools I linked to confirm the layouts are sized correctly? You also seem to be using DataBinding but then setting the textview text explicitly, that could be a problem as well. What have you done to debug? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: I solved the problem after a detailed check with the debug process afterwards, thank you.